# Beautifulsoup lost nodes

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html5lib

I am using Python and Beautifulsoup to parse HTML-Data and get p-tags out of RSS-Feeds. However, some urls cause problems because the parsed soup-object does not include all nodes of the document.

For example I tried to parse http://feeds.chicagotribune.com/~r/ChicagoBreakingNews/~3/T2Zg3dk4L88/story01.htm

But after comparing the parsed object with the pages source code, I noticed that all nodes after `ul class="nextgen-left"` are missing.

Here is how I parse the Documents:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = 'http://feeds.chicagotribune.com/~r/ChicagoBreakingNews/~3/T2Zg3dk4L88/story01.htm'

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
request = urllib2.Request(url)

response = opener.open(request) 

soup = bs(response,'lxml')        
print soup
```

Comment: Try a different parser; the HTML in the feed is broken and different parsers handle that differently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The input HTML is not quite conformant, so you'll have to use a different parser here. The `html5lib` parser handles this page correctly:

```
>>> import requests
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> r = requests.get('http://feeds.chicagotribune.com/~r/ChicagoBreakingNews/~3/T2Zg3dk4L88/story01.htm')
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
>>> soup.find('div', id='story-body') is not None
False
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html5')
>>> soup.find('div', id='story-body') is not None
True
```