# BeautifulSoup - All href links don't appear to be extracting

Tags: parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, python-3.8

I am trying to extract all href links that are within class **['address']**. Each time I run the code, I only get the first 5 and that's it, even though I know there should be 9.

Web-Page:
https://www.walgreens.com/storelocator/find.jsp?requestType=locator&state=AK&city=ANCHORAGE&from=localSearch

I have read through a variety of threads below, altered my code countless times, including switching through all parsers (html.parser, html5lib, lxml, xml, lxml-xml)  but nothing seems to be working. Any idea of what's causing it stop after the 5th iteration? I am still fairly new into python so I apologize if this is a rookie mistake that I'm overlooking. Any help would be appreciated, even the sarcastic answers :)

- [Beautiful Soup findAll doesn't find them all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16322862/beautiful-soup-findall-doent-find-them-all)
- [Beautiful Soup 4 find_all don't find links that Beautiful Soup 3 finds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17698836/beautiful-soup-4-find-all-dont-find-links-that-beautiful-soup-3-finds)
- [BeautifulSoup fails to parse long view state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18150786/beautifulsoup-fails-to-parse-long-view-state)
- [Beautifulsoup lost nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16316793/beautifulsoup-lost-nodes)
- [Missing parts on Beautiful Soup results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18614305/missing-parts-on-beautiful-soup-results)
- [Python 64 bit not storing as long of string as 32 bit python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28616558/python-64-bit-not-storing-as-long-of-string-as-32-bit-python)

I used pretty similar code on the following web-pages below and did not experience any issues scraping the hrefs:
https://www.walgreens.com/storelistings/storesbystate.jsp?requestType=locator
https://www.walgreens.com/storelistings/storesbycity.jsp?requestType=locator&state=AK

My code below:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


local_rg = requests.get('https://www.walgreens.com/storelocator/find.jsp?requestType=locator&state=AK&city=ANCHORAGE&from=localSearch')

local_rg_content = local_rg.content
local_rg_content_src = BeautifulSoup(local_rg_content, 'lxml')

for link in local_rg_content_src.find_all('div'):
    local_class = str(link.get('class'))
    if str("['address']") in str(local_class):
        local_a = link.find_all('a')
        for a_link in local_a:
            local_href = str(a_link.get('href'))
            print(local_href)
```

My results (first 5):

1. /locator/walgreens-1470+w+northern+lights+blvd-anchorage-ak-99503/id=15092
2. /locator/walgreens-725+e+northern+lights+blvd-anchorage-ak-99503/id=13656
3. /locator/walgreens-4353+lake+otis+parkway-anchorage-ak-99508/id=15653
4. /locator/walgreens-7600+debarr+rd-anchorage-ak-99504/id=12679
5. /locator/walgreens-2197+w+dimond+blvd-anchorage-ak-99515/id=12680

But should be 9:

1. /locator/walgreens-1470+w+northern+lights+blvd-anchorage-ak-99503/id=15092
2. /locator/walgreens-725+e+northern+lights+blvd-anchorage-ak-99503/id=13656
3. /locator/walgreens-4353+lake+otis+parkway-anchorage-ak-99508/id=15653
4. /locator/walgreens-7600+debarr+rd-anchorage-ak-99504/id=12679
5. /locator/walgreens-2197+w+dimond+blvd-anchorage-ak-99515/id=12680
6. /locator/walgreens-2550+e+88th+ave-anchorage-ak-99507/id=15654
7. /locator/walgreens-12405+brandon+st-anchorage-ak-99515/id=13449
8. /locator/walgreens-12051+old+glenn+hwy-eagle+river-ak-99577/id=15362
9. /locator/walgreens-1721+e+parks+hwy-wasilla-ak-99654/id=12681

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `selenium` instead of `requests` to get the source code of the page. Here is how you do it:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.walgreens.com/storelocator/find.jsp?requestType=locator&state=AK&city=ANCHORAGE&from=localSearch')

local_rg_content = driver.page_source
driver.close()
local_rg_content_src = BeautifulSoup(local_rg_content, 'lxml')
```

The rest of the code is the same. Here is the full code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.walgreens.com/storelocator/find.jsp?requestType=locator&state=AK&city=ANCHORAGE&from=localSearch')

local_rg_content = driver.page_source
driver.close()
local_rg_content_src = BeautifulSoup(local_rg_content, 'lxml')

for link in local_rg_content_src.find_all('div'):
    local_class = str(link.get('class'))
    if str("['address']") in str(local_class):
        local_a = link.find_all('a')
        for a_link in local_a:
            local_href = str(a_link.get('href'))
            print(local_href)
```

Output:

```
/locator/walgreens-1470+w+northern+lights+blvd-anchorage-ak-99503/id=15092
/locator/walgreens-725+e+northern+lights+blvd-anchorage-ak-99503/id=13656
/locator/walgreens-4353+lake+otis+parkway-anchorage-ak-99508/id=15653
/locator/walgreens-7600+debarr+rd-anchorage-ak-99504/id=12679
/locator/walgreens-2197+w+dimond+blvd-anchorage-ak-99515/id=12680
/locator/walgreens-2550+e+88th+ave-anchorage-ak-99507/id=15654
/locator/walgreens-12405+brandon+st-anchorage-ak-99515/id=13449
/locator/walgreens-12051+old+glenn+hwy-eagle+river-ak-99577/id=15362
/locator/walgreens-1721+e+parks+hwy-wasilla-ak-99654/id=12681
```

Answer (score 0):

the page uses Ajax to load store information from external URL. You can use `requests`/`json` module to load it:

```
import re
import json
import requests


url = 'https://www.walgreens.com/storelocator/find.jsp?requestType=locator&state=AK&city=ANCHORAGE&from=localSearch'
ajax_url = 'https://www.walgreens.com/locator/v1/stores/search?requestor=search'
m = re.search(r'"lat":([\d.-]+),"lng":([\d.-]+)', requests.get(url).text)

params = {
    'lat': m.group(1),
    'lng': m.group(2)
}

data = requests.post(ajax_url, json=params).json()

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

for result in data['results']:
    print(result['store']['address']['street'])
    print('https://www.walgreens.com' + result['storeSeoUrl'])
    print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
1470 W NORTHERN LIGHTS BLVD
https://www.walgreens.com/locator/walgreens-1470+w+northern+lights+blvd-anchorage-ak-99503/id=15092
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
725 E NORTHERN LIGHTS BLVD
https://www.walgreens.com/locator/walgreens-725+e+northern+lights+blvd-anchorage-ak-99503/id=13656
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4353 LAKE OTIS PARKWAY
https://www.walgreens.com/locator/walgreens-4353+lake+otis+parkway-anchorage-ak-99508/id=15653
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
7600 DEBARR RD
https://www.walgreens.com/locator/walgreens-7600+debarr+rd-anchorage-ak-99504/id=12679
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2197 W DIMOND BLVD
https://www.walgreens.com/locator/walgreens-2197+w+dimond+blvd-anchorage-ak-99515/id=12680
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2550 E 88TH AVE
https://www.walgreens.com/locator/walgreens-2550+e+88th+ave-anchorage-ak-99507/id=15654
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
12405 BRANDON ST
https://www.walgreens.com/locator/walgreens-12405+brandon+st-anchorage-ak-99515/id=13449
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
12051 OLD GLENN HWY
https://www.walgreens.com/locator/walgreens-12051+old+glenn+hwy-eagle+river-ak-99577/id=15362
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1721 E PARKS HWY
https://www.walgreens.com/locator/walgreens-1721+e+parks+hwy-wasilla-ak-99654/id=12681
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thank you @Andrej Kesely. Definitely good to know going forward in terms of the Ajax. And your code worked for me and returned the results I needed.